# Difference between ways of accessing model relations in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When accessing a model relation, what's the difference between the following:

```
$post->comments
```

Or

```
$post->comments()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

> Once the relationship is defined, we may retrieve the related record
>   using Eloquent's dynamic properties. Dynamic properties allow you to
>   access relationship functions as if they were properties defined on
>   the model

This:

```
$posts = $user->posts;
```

Is effectively the same as this:

```
$posts = $user->posts()->get();
```

Using it like this will result in getting the relationship instance:

```
$posts = $user->posts();
```

This can be handy if you want to filter it down with specific filters because you can apply the query builder to it now.

Answer (score 2):

With the `$post->comments`, you access to the [collection](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html) of comments that belong to the specific post.

On the other hand, with `$post->comments()` you access to the Post model's comments [relation](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.html) which is queryable.

Answer (score 0):

With `$post->comments()` you have a object of   `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\{relationType}` (BelongsToMany e.g.)

but with `$post->comments` you have a object of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`.